# Error jersey Rest client using sparql queries

Tags: java, rest, jersey, sparql

I am trying to execute sparql queries from jersey client  but the problem that the execution returns 200 status and the result is  null.But , when  I execute the same query on POSTMAN the status is 200 but the result is not null.

the the code for java client :

```
package org.jaba.messenger.messenger.client;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.EncoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;




public class restapiClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Client client=ClientBuilder.newClient();
        //sb simple query

         HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", "123123");
         client.register(feature);

        String query=new String("SELECT * WHERE { ?a ?b ?c }") ;
        URLCodec uc = new URLCodec();
        String sparqlQueryUri = null;


        try
        {
            sparqlQueryUri=uc.encode(query);
            System.out.println("SimpleJerseyClient(): uri = " + sparqlQueryUri);
        }catch (EncoderException e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        WebTarget target=client.target("http://localhost:8080/qodisco/api/sync-search")
                .queryParam("query",sparqlQueryUri);

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =target.request();
        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

        ;

        System.out.println(response.getStatus());


        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

that is the code of the API that I am connecting to it:

```
package br.ufrn.dimap.consiste.qodisco.api;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.ufrn.dimap.consiste.qodisco.model.entities.Domain;
import br.ufrn.dimap.consiste.qodisco.model.entities.User;
import br.ufrn.dimap.consiste.qodisco.model.enums.TopicType;
import br.ufrn.dimap.consiste.qodisco.services.APIService;
import br.ufrn.dimap.consiste.qodisco.services.FusekiService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class QoDiscoAPI {

    @Autowired
    private APIService apiService;

    @Autowired
    private FusekiService fusekiService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        if(!apiService.addUser(user)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT); 
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/sync-search", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/json")
    //@RequestParam("domain") String domain,
    public String syncSearch( @RequestParam("query") String query){
        return apiService.searchByQuery("Pollution", query);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/async-search", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/json")
    public @ResponseBody String asyncSearch(@RequestParam("query") String query, @RequestParam("domain") String domain, @RequestParam("type") int type){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = new Date();
        String topicName = "qodisco"+auth.getName()+dateFormat.format(date);
        TopicType topicType;
        switch(type){
            case 1:
                topicType = TopicType.TIPO1;
                break;

            case 2:
                topicType = TopicType.TIPO2;
                break;

            case 3:
                topicType = TopicType.TIPO3;
                break;

            default:
                topicType = null;
                break;
        }

        if(topicType!=null){
            fusekiService.asyncSearch(query, topicName, domain, topicType);
            return topicName;
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/resource", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addResource(@RequestParam("domain") String domain,
            @RequestParam("data") String data){
        apiService.createOrUpdateResource(domain, data);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/resource", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateResource(@RequestParam("domain") String domain,
            @RequestParam("data") String data){
        apiService.createOrUpdateResource(domain, data);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/resource", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> removeResource(@RequestParam("domain") String domain,
            @RequestParam("data") String data){
        apiService.createOrUpdateResource(domain, data);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/repository", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addRepository(@RequestParam("domains") List<String> domainNames,
            @RequestParam("url") String repositoryUrl, @RequestParam("operations") List<String> operations){

        if(apiService.addRepository(domainNames, repositoryUrl, operations)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else{
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);         
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/repository", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> removeRepository(@RequestParam("url") String url){
        if(apiService.removeRepository(url)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else{
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/rdo", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/json")
    public List<Domain> getRdos(HttpServletResponse response){
        return apiService.getDomains();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/rdo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addRdo(@RequestBody Domain domain){
        System.out.println(domain);
        if(apiService.addRdo(domain)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/rdo", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> removeRdo(@RequestParam("name") String name){
        if(apiService.removeDomain(name)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else{
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/rdo", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateRdo(@RequestBody Domain domain){
        if(apiService.addRdo(domain)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }
}
```

that is the result of running the client :

```
SimpleJerseyClient(): uri = SELECT+*+WHERE+%7B+%3Fa+%3Fb++%7D
200
org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$2@cd3fee8
null
```

Thanks

Comment: Your SPARQL query is strange. There are **triple** patterns expected in it and not  **pair** patterns.

Comment: By the way, any reason for doing the same operation on `/resource` even for DELETE request? Looks like a copy and paste error.

Comment: @AKSW3 I correct it in fact , It is a triple pattern in the query .

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a parsing error on the side of the endpoint. I've found that `Fuseki` (is that your underlying triple store?) requires spaces to be encoded as `%20` rather than `+`. However, I managed to run `+` encoded queries from the browser just fine. Perhaps replacing `+` with `%20` in the encoded query string will resolve the issue. Otherwise, hope someone finds this useful.

```
sparqlQueryUri = uc.encode(query).replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
```